# Swift REPL: how to import, load, evaluate, or require a .swift file?

Tags: swift, import, require, read-eval-print-loop

In the Swift REPL, how to import (a.k.a. load, evaluate, require) a typical text *.swift file?

- I want to use the code from this file: `~/src/Foo.swift`
- Syntax like this doesn't work: `import ~/src/Foo.swift`

For comparison:

- An equivalent solution in the Swift REPL for a framework is: `import Foundation`
- An equivalent solution in the Ruby REPL for a *.ruby file is: `require "~/src/foo"`

These are similar questions that are /not/ what I'm asking:

- How to use/make a Swift command-line script, executable, module, etc.
- How to use/make an XCode playground, project, library, framework, etc.
- How to launch the REPL with a pre-existing list of files.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use -I, so if your modulename.swiftmodule file is in ~/mymodules than launch swift with

```
swift -I ~/mymodules
```

and then you will be able to import your module

```
import module name
```

Should be that easy

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a way to include .swift source code, from within the Swift REPL, and also without having any special launch. For comparison in Ruby we can read in source code and evaluate it like this: require '/foo/bar/mycode.rb'

Comment: Oh my mistake... sorry... and do you need to do this dynamically (i.e. loading a string and then 'requiring' that) or do you know the desired import files at "launch time"?

Comment: Dynamically. Much like Ruby, Python, Perl, etc. let me require any arbitrary file path in the REPL at any time.

Comment: Then it's a clear no at this stage. Unless the file is compiled into a module that's then placed with the correct include and library paths.

Answer (score 3):

### In swift,you can't import a typical *.swift file.

For `Import Declaration` can only be the following syntax:

> “
>   ‌ import-declaration → attributes*opt* **import** import-kind*opt* import-path
>    import-kind → typealias| struct| class| enum| protocol| var| func
>   ‌ import-path → import-path-identifier| import-path-identifier.import-path
>   ‌ import-path-identifier → identifier| operator”
>   From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2)”。 iBooks.

which can be described as these formats:

> import `module`
>   import `import kind` `module`.`symbol name`
>   import `module`.`submodule`

`import head.swift` is incompatible with `import import-kind module.symbol-name`

---

Usually compile the files you want to import as a framework.Then it can be regarded as a module. use `-F framework_directory/` to specify 3rd-party frameworks' search path.

1. Create a file. For example:

   `// test.swift
   import headtest
   print("Hello World")`
2. open your terminal
3. goto the directory where you create the file.
4. execute command line

   `swift -F headtest test.swift`

And done.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I'll try your way until there's a positive answer to my question. Much obliged.

Comment: Could you write function that takes a path,  compiles it, and imports it dynamically? Then just always include that function when you launch the repl?

Answer (score 2):

Now Swift REPL supports packages. We can do this by the following steps:

1. In Xcode, select menu File > New > Package. Choose a name for the package, for example MyLibrary.
2. Copy your codes or .swift files to the Sources/MyLibrary/ directory in your package.
3. Remember to make your interface `public`.
4. In the command line, go to the package directory and run REPL

Like this

```
cd MyLibrary/
swift run --repl
```

5. In the REPL, import your library

Like this

```
import MyLibrary
```

Now you can your codes in the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

Simply insert the shebang line at the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I'm looking for is a way to load the file's code into the REPL; I'm not seeking a way to make the file's code executable. I'll clarify my question. -Joel

Comment: Though overkill, you could build a dynamic library and load it into the REPL.

Comment: Thanks Vatsal. Yes, that's a good idea and my fallback if no one here can come up with a solution that loads the plain text into the REPL. I'll clarify my question more. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm looking into this as we speak. But, if it's an option, consider building a proper framework (using Xcode), and then load it into the REPL.

Comment: Might not have helped as a answer to this specific question but that is very neat to know about. Its a really nice option in some circumstances to be able to call all sorts of native code from a script this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy/paste the source code into the repl and execute it.
Not ideal, obviously, but sometimes useful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not possible to import file and get Xcode to use REPL for it using specifications you gave. I think you can still do it creating a proper framework, but it's not *exactly* what you was looking.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for an answer using the specifications I gave in the question.