# Swift REPL how to add framework to script

Tags: mysql, swift, read-eval-print-loop

**Problem**

I'm tring to make simple Swift script using Swift REPL and MySQL connector from Perfect.

My directory looks like this

```
/Users/Me/Desktop/test
    |-sqlTest.swift
    |-MySQL.framework
```

According to [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36235186/989631) command to launch script should look be

```
swift -I ~/Desktop/test/ sqlTest.swift
```

but instead of success I'm getting

> sqlTest.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'MySQL'

**Question**

So how I should add framework to REPL or maybe this is not possible at all?

Comment: Old video about swift scripting. At the end there was method how to link against framework: https://realm.io/news/swift-scripting/

Answer (score 0):

Ok turns out the right command pattern is

```
xcrun swift -F <path to direction with modules> <swift file>
```

So in my situation looks like this.

```
xcrun swift -F ~/Desktop/test/ sqlTest.swift
```

But not every module will work and atm I don't know why. Also there is some problem use frameworks at Ubuntu. Swift REPL seams to not detect frameworks.