# Howto load SwiftPM project + its dependencies in Swift repl

Tags: swift

Let's say I make a project "Bar", like so:

```
~ $ mkdir Bar
~ $ cd Bar/
Bar $ swift package init --type library
Bar $ git init .
Bar $ git add .
Bar $ git commit -m "Initial commit"
Bar $ git tag 1.0.0
Bar $ swift build
```

If I then try to *i)* use a 3rd party dependency (let's say [Alamofire/Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)), then try to *ii)* import that dependency or *iii)* the project  module in the repl, I get a load error.

```
$ swift

  1> import Bar
error: repl.swift:1:8: error: no such module Bar'
import Bar
       ^

  1> import Alamofire
error: repl.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'Alamofire'
import Alamofire
       ^
```

How do I load my Swift Package Manager project + its dependencies in the Swift repl?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872589/swift-repl-how-to-import-load-evaluate-or-require-a-swift-file ?

Comment: Thanks @Moritz, that sheds some light. These two approaches still both give the same error though. `swift -F .build/checkouts/Alamofire.git-6801331143877184500/` and `swift -I .build/checkouts/Alamofire.git-6801331143877184500/`.

Comment: I've finally found a solution, check my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*These are the steps to follow for a solution using Swift 4.*

Create a folder, let's say "TestSPMLibrary":

```
$ mkdir TestSPMLibrary
$ cd TestSPMLibrary
```

Create a library package:

```
$ swift package init --type library
```

**In the "Package.swift" file, add the ".dynamic" library type.**

You can also add a dependency such as Alamofire (you need to also add it to the target).

My "Package.swift" example:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "TestSPMLibrary",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "TestSPMLibrary",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["TestSPMLibrary"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git", from: "4.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "TestSPMLibrary",
            dependencies: ["Alamofire"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "TestSPMLibraryTests",
            dependencies: ["TestSPMLibrary"]),
    ]
)
```

In this library the code you want to interface with has to be declared public (and objects need a public initializer).

My "TestSPMLibrary.swift" example:

```
public struct Blah {
    public init() {}
    public var text = "Hello, World!"
}
```

Build the library:

```
$ swift build
```

Launch the REPL with `swift -I .build/debug -L .build/debug -l` and add the library name. In my case:

```
$ swift -I .build/debug -L .build/debug -lTestSPMLibrary
```

In the REPL you can now import your library (and its dependencies):

```
import TestSPMLibrary
import Alamofire

let x = Blah()
print(x.text)
```